# sed delete multi lines after a match then do replace

Tags: sed

I have a file `/etc/config/network`

```
config interface loopback
        option ifname   lo
        option proto    static
        option ipaddr   127.0.0.1
        option netmask  255.0.0.0

config interface lan
        option ifname   eth0
        option type     none
        option proto    static
        option ipaddr   192.168.1.1
        option netmask  255.255.255.0

config interface debug
        option ifname   usb0
        option type     none
        option proto    static
        option ipaddr   172.18.0.18
        option netmask  255.255.255.0
```

I want to rewrite it to be

```
config interface loopback
    option ifname   lo
    option proto    static
    option ipaddr   127.0.0.1
    option netmask  255.0.0.0

config interface lan
    option ifname   eth0
    option type     none
    option proto    dhcp

config interface debug
    option ifname   usb0
    option type     none
    option proto    static
    option ipaddr   172.18.0.18
    option netmask  255.255.255.0
```

I proceed this in this way:

1. find `static` then delete two lines after(exclude line `static`)
2. replace `static` with `dhcp`

Tried using `sed '/static/{n;d}' /etc/config/network | sed -e 's/static/dhcp/' -e '/dhcp/{n;d}' > /etc/config/network` which is not so neat.

Could this be like `sed -i -e <delete pattern> -e <replace pattern> /etc/config/network` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -i.bak '/config interface lan/,/^$/{/static/{N;N;s/static.*/dhcp/}}' /etc/config/network
config interface loopback
        option ifname   lo
        option proto    static
        option ipaddr   127.0.0.1
        option netmask  255.0.0.0

config interface lan
        option ifname   eth0
        option type     none
        option proto    dhcp

config interface debug
        option ifname   usb0
        option type     none
        option proto    static
        option ipaddr   172.18.0.18
        option netmask  255.255.255.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `awk` would be a good choice for this type of text processing. It gives you great opportunity for customization.

```
/^config interface/ { interface=$3; option="" }
$1=="option" { option=$2 }

interface == "lan" && option == "proto" { $3 = "dhcp" }
interface == "lan" && ( option == "ipaddr" || option == "netmask") { option=""; next }
```

And if the formatting bothers you, you might replace the line that sets $3 with:

```
interface == "lan" && option == "proto" { gsub(/static/,"dhcp",$0) }
```

Of course, if you still do want to just one-off this in sed, and the input file is always going to be formatted that way, something like this might be sufficient:

```
sed '/config interface lan/,/^$/{s/static/dhcp/;/ipaddr/d;/netmask/d;}'
```

This works by considering the space between "`config interface lan`" and the next blank line, to restrict the commands to those inside the curly braces. It can adjust to some slight variations in options order, but it needs that blank line.

Comment: Not my downvote. I assume it is because a solution is being searched with `sed`.

Comment: @Cyrus .. Perhaps, but the OP created the question with other tags, the sed restriction was applied by someone else in an edit.. Also, I *did* provide a sed alternative. <sigh>